# Connect to mysql with java app of pc client

Tags: java

i have install mysql to a windows pc (with ip 192.168.1.100)
and i have made a java application

when a run the application to the same pc with mysql it's runing

```
String userName = "root";
String password = "1234";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/emi";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

i can't run it from other pc in the same network. the code i use is

```
String userName = "root";
String password = "1234";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.100:3306/emi";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

Should I make MySQL Workbench to alow connection from pther pc?

Comment: What is the exception stacktrace? Check to make sure you have enabled the credentials to log in from remote pc. Also, you should ***not*** be using the root credentials in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to grant rights to the IP address.

Execute on the command line (cmd.exe):

```
C:\....> mysql -uroot -p 1234
mysql> GRANT ALL ON emi.* TO root@'192.168.1.100' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
mysql> \q
```

And the Windows firewall might block port 3306.

Maybe you should first create a user **emiuser**, if you do not want full root rights from a remote PC.

You can then locally test 192.168.1.100:3306.

Comment: in my firewall(windows 7) MySQL55 profile is ALL, Enabled, Action is Allow, Remote Address is Any I'm new user and i do not understand what you write. if you say them step by step, it would be nice
thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer to say where to run this. You could also run this `GRANT ...` in Java. And then MySQL offers a MySQL workbench too.